# How to pass a variable to modal from a for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have for loop where I call a partial for each iteration of the loop:

```
<% applications.each do |application| %>
   <td>
     <%= render :partial => "layouts/form", :locals => {:@application => application} %>
   </td>
<% end %>
```

Now, within the partial, I have a button which when pressed would display a modal:

```
<button type="button" class="button-custom btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form-modal"> <%= "#{button_text}" %> </button>
<div id="form-modal" class="modal fade modal-form" role="dialog" tabindex='-1'>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <td> <%= "#{@application.name}" %> </td>
```

The problem now is that `@application.name` always refers to the value of the first application within the for loop. It does not get the value  corresponding the respective iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@` sign from `application` variable.

```
 <%= render :partial => "layouts/form", :locals => {:application => application} %>
 ....

<td> <%= application.name %> </td>
```

You should generate an unique modal id for every application.

```
data-target="#form-modal-<%= application.id %>"

<div id="form-modal-<%= application.id %>"
```

Comment: The answer is updated. You should generate an unique modal id.

Comment: Awesome! That did the track. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, it wasn't required to remove the @ sign though